# How to get the page number in ms word using c#

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word

how can i get the page number in ms word using Namespace

```
microsoft.office.interop.word in C#.
```

please help me.......

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the `Document.ComputeStatistics` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.computestatistics.aspx

For details, please refer to my previous answer on a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12339712/700926