# How to programatically (C#) determine the pages count of .docx files

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have about 400 files in .docx format, and I need to determine the length of each in #pages.

So, I want to write C# code for selecting the folder that contains the documents , and then returns the #pages of each .docx file.

Answer (score 20):

To illustrate how this can be done, I have just created a C# console application based on .NET 4.5 and some of the Microsoft Office 2013 COM objects.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordDocStats
{
    class Program
    {
        // Based on: http://www.dotnetperls.com/word
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Open a doc file.
            var application = new Application();
            var document = application.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\MyName\Documents\word.docx");

            // Get the page count.
            var numberOfPages = document.ComputeStatistics(WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages, false);

            // Print out the result.
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Total number of pages in document: {0}", numberOfPages));

            // Close word.
            application.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work you need to reference the following COM objects:

- Microsoft Office Object Library (version 15.0 in my case)
- Microsoft Word Object Library (version 15.0 in my case)

The two COM objects gives you access to the namespaces needed.

For details on how to reference the correct assemblies, please refer to section: "3. Setting Up Work Environment:" at: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx

For a quick and more general introduction to Word automation through C#, see: http://www.dotnetperls.com/word

-- UPDATE

Documentation about the method `Document.ComputeStatistics` that gives you access to the page count can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.computestatistics.aspx

As seen in the documentation, the method takes a `WdStatistic` enum that enables you to retrieve different kinds of stats, e.g., the total amount of pages. For an overview of the complete range of stats you have access to, please refer to the documentation of the `WdStatistic` enum, which can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdstatistic.aspx

Answer (score 4):

use DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll you can find dll in C:\Program Files\Open XML SDK\V2.0\lib

Sample code:

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument doc = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument.Open(docxPath, false);
            MessageBox.Show(doc.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties.Pages.InnerText.ToString());
```

to use DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument class you need to add following references in your project

DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll &
Windowsbase.dll

Comment: I have wrote the following code to perform the mission in a windows application, but I have got the errors:

Comment: @AyaZoghby Can you give me error details ? because in My PC It's working fine.

Comment: It works with .doc files?? or just with .docx(based on openxml)?

Comment: @AndersonRissardi I believe it will work with only docx.

Comment: this is a nice solution if you don't want to have MS Office (DLLs) installed on your server

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spire.Doc page count is  free :)

```cs
using Spire.Doc;
    public sealed class TestNcWorker
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void DocTemplate3851PageCount()
        {
            var docTemplate3851 = Resource.DocTemplate3851;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Write(docTemplate3851, 0, docTemplate3851.Length);
                Document document = new Document();
                document.LoadFromStream(ms, FileFormat.Docx);
                Assert.AreEqual(2,document.PageCount);
            }
            var barCoder = new BarcodeAttacher("8429053", "1319123", "HR3514");
            var barcoded = barCoder.AttachBarcode(docTemplate3851).Value;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Write(barcoded, 0, barcoded.Length);
                Document document = new Document();
                document.LoadFromStream(ms, FileFormat.Docx);
                Assert.AreEqual( 3, document.PageCount);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern solution (based on [Jignesh Thakker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12339771/653457)): Open XML SDK is no longer there, but it is [published on Github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) and even support .NET Core. You do not need MS Office on the server/running machine.

Install the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml):

```
Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml
```

The code:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

private int CountWordPage(string filePath)
{
    using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, false))
    {
        return int.Parse(wordDocument.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties.Pages.Text);
    }
}
```