# how can i get text per page from doc file in c#?

Tags: c#, ms-office

I'm getting text from whole pages of doc file in c# using `microsoft.office.interop.word` reference library:

```
string docPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/profile/" + pic);
Application app = new Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open(docPath);
string words = doc.Content.Text;
```

But how can I get text per page from doc file?

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987095/get-pages-of-word-document)? or I am getting it wrong?

Comment: yehh... but i got the null value in start object when the line
" Start = WordApplication.Selection.GoTo(ref What, ref Which, ref CurrentPageNumber, ref Miss).Start;" was executed.

Comment: Refer http://shaunakelly.com/word/word-development/selecting-or-referring-to-a-page-in-the-word-object-model.html. As per it, its not always possible to get text as per page. Do you really want to work as pages or sections. If its sections, I can share the code I have.

Comment: thnx for the reference link. I didn't know that :)