# How to get printing pages count

Tags: wpf, printing, exe

I am developing one exe file. That purpose is to get the count of Printing Pages. If I take print in word or excel or pdf. I want to get the count of printing pages and displayed in label through that exe application. I am using WPF. How to do. Please tell me.

Comment: show some code, what did you try so far?

Comment: I am creating the browsing centre software to manage the user activity. I capture the user name, user mobile no, login time, logout time and also want to take the print pages and the timer also run in it. If the user take some print then it display the count of print pages. How to get the print pages count and display in it.

Answer (score 0):

There are different scenarios depending on whether the document is Word, Excel or pdf.

If its Word, see [How to programatically (C#) determine the pages count of .docx files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12339553/107409).

If its pdf, see [Determine number of pages in a PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320281/determine-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-file).

If its Excel, then you might have to use another technique, I'm not sure.